# Why does SQLite tell me "No current row"?

Tags: c#, sqlite

The query being sent is good; running it:

```
SELECT line_id, description, department, upc_pack_size, pack_size, unit_cost, unit_list FROM Inventory WHERE siteNum = "03" AND upc_code = "76145513"
```

...in LINQPad returns a record with these values:

```
line_id = 0
description = [empty string]
department = 2.99
upc_pack_size = 333
pack_size = 333
unit_cost = 50.01
unit_list = 50.99
```

But the code:

```
public List<String> GetDynamicINVValsForUPCCode(String qry, String siteNum, String upcCode)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("Reached TestHHSDBUtils.GetDynamicINVValsForUPCCode(); siteNum is {0}; upcCode is {1}; qry is {2}", siteNum, upcCode, qry));
    List<String> dsdValsForUPCCode = new List<string>(); 
    try
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("upcCode", upcCode));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("SiteNum", siteNum));
                using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Line_id"]));       // Line_id, int32
                    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Description"]));   // Description
                    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Department"]));    // Department
                    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Upc_pack_size"])); // Upc_pack_size (int32)
                    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Pack_size"]));     // Pack_size (int32)
                    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Unit_qty"]));      // Unit_qty (single)
                }
            }
            return dsdValsForUPCCode;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format("{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From TestHHSDBUtils.GetDynamicINVValsForUPCCode: {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
        return null;
    }
}
```

...fails, the err being logged as:

```
Message: From TestHHSDBUtils.GetDynamicINVValsForUPCCode: No current row; Inner Ex: ; Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.CheckValidRow()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at HHS.TestHHSDBUtils.GetDynamicINVValsForUPCCode(String qry, String siteNum, String upcCode)
```

Why does it say "no current row" when there is one?

Comment: What is the value of `qry`?

Comment: It's given at the very beginning of the post.

Comment: If you are passing that into your function, then what is the point of setting the parameters?

Comment: Sorry - qry is: 
SELECT line_id, description, department, upc_pack_size, pack_size, unit_cost, unit_list FROM Inventory WHERE siteNum = [at sign]SiteNum AND upc_code = [at sign]upcCode

Comment: Shouldn't the code use the `@` sign in the parameter name? For example, `new SQLiteParameter("@upcCode", upcCode)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While I'm not explicitly familiar with the SqlLiteReader, but the rest of the readers require you to read the first row.  I'm using an `if` statement but where you are expecting numerrous rows you would use a `while`.  The DataReader.Read() returns a boolean to indicate if a record has been read.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  if (rdr.Read()){
    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Line_id"]));       // Line_id, int32
    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Description"]));   // Description
    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Department"]));    // Department
    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Upc_pack_size"])); // Upc_pack_size (int32)
    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Pack_size"]));     // Pack_size (int32)
    dsdValsForUPCCode.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Unit_qty"]));      // Unit_qty (single)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set the parameters, the parameter name needs the `@` prefix to work. So your code should instead read:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@upcCode", upcCode));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@SiteNum", siteNum));
```

Additionally (as pointed out in other answers) you also need to perform a `Read()` on the reader first:

```
rdr.Read();
```

Comment: Really? I have that in *none* of the Parameters in this project, and everything (but this method) works fine. And I think this one will, now that I've added the "rdr.Read()"

Answer (score 1):

same problem here while building vb.net using sqlite, and found out that after you use `executereader`, you need to use `read()` from object `sqlitedatareader` to read

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I belive SQLite requires parameters to have '@', ':' or '$' prefixed names. [Source](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

So your query should be like:

```
SELECT line_id, description, department, upc_pack_size, pack_size, unit_cost, unit_list FROM Inventory WHERE siteNum = @siteNum AND upc_code = @upcCode
```

And your paramaters like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@siteNum", siteNum));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@upcCode", upcCode));
```

Comment: I am using "@"s, you just don't see them above; the query I show is what it resolves to. I'm showing exactly what I gave to LINQPad (which would have frowned on the @s).

Comment: qry is: SELECT line_id, description, department, upc_pack_size, pack_size, unit_cost, unit_list FROM Inventory WHERE siteNum = [at sign]SiteNum AND upc_code = [at sign]upcCode

Comment: Still, to my knowledge, SQLiteParameter needs the "@" in the name, also.

Comment: Also, @THBBFT's answer is what I think you should look into.